# StackExchange API, OAuth for other sites than Stack Overflow

Tags: support, api-v2.2, stackauth

I'm implementing the OAuth system through StackExchange API, [here is the guide](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication#scope).

I've already integrated the OAuth system with stack overflow with the following parameters:

- Token URL: https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/access_token/json
- Auth URL: https://stackexchange.com/oauth

And it works just fine!

My question is: how do I integrate other sites? Where can I find the auth url to pass in the OAuth flow?
For example to OAuth to mathematics, this OAuth URL: https://mathematics.com/oauth/access_token/json doesn't work!

What should I use to perform the OAuth flow to other sites like Super User, Stack Apps, Stack Exchange, Mathematics etc...? Where can I find the correct URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have the correct URL. The access token is valid for *all* sites, even those for which you don't have an account. The [documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/) explains how to switch to a different site than Stack Overflow:

> #### Per-Site Methods
>
> Each of these methods operates on a single site at a time, identified by the `site` parameter. This parameter can be the full domain name (ie. "stackoverflow.com"), or a short form identified by `api_site_parameter` on the [site object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/site).

Comment: Oh I didn't know that!
May I ask: I fetched /me/associated to retrieve the list of channels I'm associated with. And it returns a list.

If I perform some actions lets say with StackExchange it works! But If I do it with Super User I receive: "The account associated with the access_token doesn't have a user on the site" even if it is returned from me/associated

Comment: What I meant was: you can use the same token to e.g. fetch questions from sites you don't have an account on. `me/associated` doesn't accept a `site` parameter, because it's a **Network Method**; *These methods return data across the entire Stack Exchange network of sites. Accordingly, you do not pass a site parameter to them.*